# I need a script to detect if a computer is in an active directory user group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, jscript, sccm

I found online a VBscript that joins a computer to a group in the Users OU for Direct Access to work. It works perfectly in the task sequence for our OSD using SCCM 2012 but we've come to a road block where we only want laptops to be added rather then all computers.

If someone would be so kind, I need a script (Powershell, VB, JScript) that will detect that the computer was added to the group in AD.

Comment: What have you tried, as this would not be difficult in any language... Also, are you seeing failures? Often, sometimes, or just being careful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the task sequence step to run based on a condition.

[image]

The above conditions detects if the computer is a laptop. The first one will only work when you have MDT integrated and the second uses a simple WMI query to detect the system type.

The WMI query might not be as reliable, so I would advice you integrate MDT into your environment.

Comment: I didn't know we could of added conditions. This works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this in PowerShell to check that the named computer is in the OU or not:

**Script:**

```
import-module activedirectory

$OU = @() 
$CheckOU = "LaptopOU"
$computerName = "Laptop12345"

$user = get-adcomputer $computerName -Properties *
$user.DistinguishedName -split "," | %{If($_ -match "OU="){$OU += $_ -replace "OU=",""}}

If($OU -match $CheckOU){
    "Computer:$computerName is in the OU:$CheckOU"
    # Do something...
}
Else{
    "Computer:$computerName is not in the OU:$CheckOU"
    # Do something else..
}
```

This will take a `$computerName` and get all the OU's that it's in from Active Directory and stores them in an `$OU` array.

Then you can use that array to simply check if the computer is in the given OU (`$CheckOU`) or not by using the `-match` operator.

**Note:** You need to make sure that you import the `activedirectory` module. If you do not have this to import follow this link for how to get it: [activedirectory module](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rkramesh/archive/2012/01/17/how-to-add-active-directory-module-in-powershell-in-windows-7.aspx)

For more Cmdlet's and syntax on the Powershell Active Directory module follow this [Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx)