# Active directory groups of a computer in powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

If `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` shows me what groups a user account is in, what would you use to look up a computer? I would like to display this in powershell as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was asked before and some solutions were posted in these threads:

[I need a script to detect if a computer is in an active directory user group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752248/i-need-a-script-to-detect-if-a-computer-is-in-an-active-directory-user-group)

[PowerShell: Get membership info for a computer account (not a user account)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144849/powershell-get-membership-info-for-a-computer-account-not-a-user-account)

Comment: Solution: Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership (Get-ADComputer SNA00760856).DistinguishedName

Comment: You can also simply do Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership SNA00760856$. Note the $ sign at the end computername.

Comment: What does that $ mean being at the end like that?

Comment: the dollar sign at the end of the computer name is the SamAccountName. Do a Get-ADComputer and you will see it.